# Data of Partial page is not binding in viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

ViewModel:

```
public class AdminAddMovieDataBase
    {
        public MovieInformation MovieInformation { get; set; }
        public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
  }
```

BasePage:

```
<div class="contentWrapper1">
  <div class="contentLeft1">Title</div>
  <div>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MovieInformation.MovieTitle, new { @class = "signupinputnameField", id = "movieTitle" }) </div>
  </div>
  <div id="genre">
  <div class="contentLeft1">Genre</div>
  @Html.Partial("_GenrePartialPage", Model.Genres)
  </div>
```

Partial Page:

```
<div class="ContentWrapper1">

  <ul><li>
     @Html.DropDownList("GenreList", new SelectList(Model, "GenreID", "GenreName"), "--Select Genre--", new { @class = "contentRightOption1" })
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Delete</a>
      </li></ul>
  </div>
```

When I click on the save button of form of Base page(which I have not given here in sample code). I can get the data of MovieInformation model but not of the data of  Genres which are in partial page. I couldnot bind the viewmodel using partial page. Thank you.

Comment: Partial page gets data from viewModel but selected data is not fetched  on posting (ie. AdminAddMovieDataBase.Genres is null on HttpPost)

Answer (score 0):

Your Genre list on the view model should be a `List<SelectListItem>` and you should also include a string property in your model. For this example sake we will call it MyGenre.
You can then use

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Genre.MyGenre, model=>model.Genre.GenreList)`

So the first property from the model is a string, the second is your list of SelectListItem. When the form posts you can get selected item from the string.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but Same things happen. Data comes null on Model.Genres when I post. I have passed List<Genre> to partial page not SelectList but it is converted to SelectList item.

Comment: When you put breakpoints on the view, does the Genre have data?

Comment: My problem is what you are asking for.Genre does not have data. It shows null on posting though MovieInformation is binding easily(and it should).

Comment: ah ok, if it is being passed to the view as null, you need to show code from here it gets the data, there is either a problem with the controller or your data access layer. You should place breakpoints to track figure out what area of code is failing and then post that as a code sample. The code posted doesn't help identify the issue if the model is null before it arrives to the view.

Comment: No, no , no, you took it wrong. Genre is passed to the partial page(view) and it is binded in dropdown. What I could not get is selected data of genre dropdown on posting from base page. ie. Genre Model class is not binded in [HttpPost].